# FTP connection command fails

Tags: ftp, terminal, connection

Ftp via Terminal works perfectly if you use the command prompts like this:

```
Ftp 
open
  enter hostname
  enter username
  enter password
```

But if you attempt to open a connection like this:

```
ftp ftp://username:password@hostname/path
```

End up with:

```
Trying 23.102.24.18... 
Connected to waws-prod-db5-091.drip.azurewebsites.windows.net. 
220 Microsoft FTP Service 
331 Password required 
530 User cannot log in. 
ftp: Login failed 
ftp: Can't connect or login to host waws-prod-db5-091.drip.azurewebsites.windows.net 
221 Goodbye.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What platform do you run this on? I do get different results both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I am running on a mac in terminal... it doesn't work.  I ended up getting the FireFTP plugin and was able to connect that way.  Additionally, if you use the same command in the Firefox url it works.  Same thing in Chrome doesn't.  So I guess the command is correct, but like you mention... platform dependent